# To print Glossary of Chemical symbols correctly

Tags: glossaries, mhchem

Code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries} % Load the package
\makeglossaries % Generate the glossary
\usepackage{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{co2}{name=CO2, description={Carbon Dioxide}}

Calculation of the corresponding \gls{co2} emissions to cover the surplus in electricity demand. 

\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Abbreviations}]
% \printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I read this [page](http://texblog.org/2014/01/15/glossary-and-list-of-acronyms-with-latex/) for its implementation.
I get

[image]

where you see another problem is that the symbol is not printed correctly with subscript.

I would like to get a section "Abbreviations of Glossaries", example output with many items

[image]

**How can you print the glossary correctly with the section?**

**How can print the glossary reference correctly of a chemical symbol?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in mhchem answer, use `\ce{CO2}` to get the right formatting.

If you want to get your "List of Abbreviations" printed, load the `glossaries` package with the option `acronym`

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} % Load the package
```

and define your entries as acronyms *before* `\begin{document}`, e.g.

```
\newacronym{co2}{\ce{CO2}}{Carbon Dioxide}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries} % Load the package
\makeglossaries % Prepare the glossary
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\newacronym{co2}{\ce{CO2}}{Carbon Dioxide}

\begin{document}

Calculation of the corresponding \gls{co2} emissions to cover
the surplus in electricity demand.

\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Abbreviations}]
%\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Not to have a page number like in the example of the body, you can use `\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}` where the option `nonumberlist`.

Comment: @Masi of course.

Answer (score 1):

This is a first step towards your answer. To get the chemical symbols, use this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries} % Load the package
%\makeglossaries % Prepare the glossary
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\newglossaryentry{co2}{name={\ce{CO2}}, description={Carbon Dioxide}}

Calculation of the corresponding \gls{co2} emissions to cover
the surplus in electricity demand. 

%\printglossary[type=acronym,title={List of Abbreviations}]
% \printglossaries

\end{document}
```

During testing, I had to delete the .glsdefs file every time I changed the gloassary entry.

What you need now, is to run a sorting program over the .gls file. You have to tell it, that the sort key for `\ce{CO2}` should be `CO2`. Someone else might help you with this.

Comment: I found this command `\glsresetall` which you can add to the end of the file after printing the glossary. Then, you do not need to delete `.glsdefs` file.